# Check if an application is installed from Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play

I work on an application and I add a feature which is specifically prohibited by Google Play rules. So I want this specific feature to be disabled for those who installed the application from Google Play without creating a different apk. That means that I need to determine from the code whether the application is installed from Google Play or just by downloading the apk.

Is there a way this be achieved?

Comment: Why not just publish two different versions of the app, one without the feature (which goes on Play) and one which does contain it (which goes elsewhere)?

Comment: @JoeC well before I do that I want to make sure I really need to

Comment: I guess that forbidden feature will be found because it is part of your code base, regardless of if you execute it or not.

Comment: @Marged a disabled feature doesn't make the application violate the rules as far as I understand them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for that purpose, taken from HockeyAppSDK for Android Github [library](https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Android/blob/develop/hockeysdk/src/main/java/net/hockeyapp/android/UpdateManager.java#L215):

```
protected static boolean installedFromMarket(WeakReference<? extends Context> weakContext) {
    boolean result = false;

    Context context = weakContext.get();
    if (context != null) {
        try {
            String installer = context.getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(context.getPackageName());
            // if installer string is not null it might be installed by market
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(installer)) {
                result = true;

                // on Android Nougat and up when installing an app through the package installer (which HockeyApp uses itself), the installer will be
                // "com.google.android.packageinstaller" or "com.android.packageinstaller" which is also not to be considered as a market installation
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N && (TextUtils.equals(installer, INSTALLER_PACKAGE_INSTALLER_NOUGAT) || TextUtils.equals(installer, INSTALLER_PACKAGE_INSTALLER_NOUGAT2))) {
                    result = false;
                }

                // on some devices (Xiaomi) the installer identifier will be "adb", which is not to be considered as a market installation
                if (TextUtils.equals(installer, INSTALLER_ADB)) {
                    result = false;
                }
            }

        } catch (Throwable ignored) {
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

However, I'd suggest to build two different apps for that purpose. If you're including forbidden code in Google Play, although it won't be executed helped by this method, it will be part of your *bytecode* and it's very likely to be banned by Google. It's much more cleaner to strip that out of your code by creating another flavour.

Comment: That seems to be precisely what I looked for. Even if I'll go with the second option is is still nice to have this one